# Swift + SpriteKit - Detect Long Press End

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to figure out how to detect when the user has stopped holding down on a button. I am trying to get the background to continuously scroll and to animate a character to simulate a walking effect.

To move the background I have this in **GameScene.Swift**:

```
 override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

        background.position = CGPoint(x: background.position.x - 5, y: background.position.y)
        backgroundRepeated.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundRepeated.position.x - 5, y: backgroundRepeated.position.y)

        if (background.position.x < -background.size.width) {
            background.position = CGPointMake(backgroundRepeated.position.x + backgroundRepeated.size.width, background.position.y)
        }

        if (backgroundRepeated.position.x < -backgroundRepeated.size.width) {
            backgroundRepeated.position = CGPointMake(background.position.x + background.size.width, backgroundRepeated.position.y)
        }

}
```

Which works fine for moving the background. Then I had the problem of somehow getting the elements on the **GameViewController.Swift** to do things.

So, I solved this by making an IBAction on the GameViewController which when the user holds the long press it will create an NSUserDefaults entry:

```
gameActions.setObject(true, forKey: "Walking")
```

and then I wrapped the above code in an if:

```
let startWalking = gameActions.boolForKey("Walking")
if (startWalking == true) {
    //stuff to animate
}
```

## My Questions

**1)** How do I detect when the user has stopped holding down the button. I have seen **UIGestureRecognizer.Ended** but I cannot see how to implement it.

Comment: Not sure if `UIGestureRecognizer` is what you want,  Is your button a `UIButton` or an `SKNode` in `SpriteKit`

Comment: I am new to this so I do appreciate your help :)

Comment: Then just create an ibaction for touch down inside for when you start pushing the button ibaction for touch up inside,  thats when you let go of the button, you may want touch up outside also

Comment: Do you want `override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)` and other things listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class)?

Comment: @LandSeagull Hi, thanks for the reply. To be honest I am not sure what I need. What I want is this: When the user holds down over a UIButton or SKNode image a function will fire. When the user takes there finger off the button/node then I would like another function to run. Does that make sense?